# What am i doing in the code below that is causing me to get errors?

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors

I am getting following errors:

1) Non-optional expression of type 'UITableViewCell' used in a check for optionals

2) Value of type 'UITableViewCell' has no member 'congigureCell'
Please

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if let cell:UITableViewCell = countryList.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")! as UITableViewCell // Error 1 happens here {

            let text: String!

            if inSearchMode {

                text = filteredCountriesList[indexPath.row]

            } else {

                text = countriesList[indexPath.row]
            }

            cell.congigureCell(text: text) // Error 2 happens here

            return cell

        } else {

            return UITableViewCell()
        }

    }
```

Comment: `configureCell` maybe?

Comment: If any answer solves your problem accept that answer so that later users can benefit from that.

Answer (score 2):

1) The ! mark at the end of

```
countryList.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
```

uses force unwrap to make it non-optional, so you shouldn't check it inside **if let**, or even better way is to just remove ! mark

2) **congigureCell** probably the method of different class, not **UITableViewCell**. You should substitude **UITableViewCell** by this class to cast it

Comment: How can I accomplish #2?

I found a way around #1.

Comment: your configureCell is probably defined in some class. change UITableViewCell in your code to this class

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have done following steps.

1. Add cell identifier in storyboard to your custom cell. i.e "cell"
2. Assign delegate and datasource of your `YourTableview` to `YOURViewController.swift` via storyboard or in code.
3. In `YOURViewController.swift` access cell using datasource of table
   view as.
4. Add a custom class of sub class UITableViewCell and assign it to
   tour cell in storyboard.

   `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath:` `IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {`

   ```
   if let cell = countryList.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! YOURTableViewCellClass  {

       let text: String!

       if inSearchMode {

           text = filteredCountriesList[indexPath.row]

       } else {

           text = countriesList[indexPath.row]
       }

       cell.congigureCell(text: text) // Error 2 happens here

       return cell }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

1. The ! mark is uses to force unwrap the optional value that can be nil. But "if let" and "guard let" has been check for optionals, so you don't need ! mark.

Just use

```
if let cell:UITableViewCell = countryList.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as UITableViewCell
```

2. cell in this line is '**UITableViewCell**', but congigureCell is not a member of UITableViewCell.
   If you want to use your own cell(like **MyCell**), you should convert it to MyCell.

`let myCell = cell as! MyCell`

Answer (score 1):

1 .Instead of dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: the later one never provides a nil value so you dont need to worry about the 'nil error'.

2.UItableViewCell dont have configure cell or congigureCell as in your case instead you have to create a custom tableViewCell and add function as configureCell() and then in this line

**if let cell:UITableViewCell = countryList.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")! as UITableViewCell**

replace **as UITableViewCell** as **as yourCustomTableViewCellClass**